# Apache camel-K: Problem with ActiveMQ emitter instantiation

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am a novice in Apache camel and even more in camel-K. I am building a Kubernetes-containerized stack with an ActiveMQ message queue as inbound interface to external data sources, an InfluxDB as data store and a Camel-K route for message routing from AMQ to InfluxDB.
Besides the Camel-K route, the system is running fine. I expose port 61616 of ActiveMQ to the cluster via a static-IP endpoint assigned to a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: activemq-external
spec:
  selector:
    app: activemq
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: port-service-console
      port: 8161
      targetPort: 8161
      nodePort: 8161
      protocol: TCP
---
# Service definition for internal service with static IP (which can be used in camel-K integration "ActiveMQToInfluxDB.yaml")
# see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-resource
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: activemq-internal
spec:
#  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: port-internal
      port: 61616
      targetPort: 61616
#      nodePort: 61616
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: activemq-internal
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.17.0.8
    ports:
      - port: 61616
```

Hence I expect the port should be accessible to other pods in the cluster via 172.17.0.8:61616.

I am running the camel-K route by the command (never mind the dependency to apache commons, I need this for string manipulation)

```
kamel run kamel-integrations/ActiveMQToInfluxDbRoute.java -d mvn:org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9 -d mvn:org.influxdb:influxdb-java:2.17 -d mvn:org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel:5.15.11 -d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.25.0
```

The java code of the integration looks as follows:

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.BindToRegistry;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.influxdb.dto.BatchPoints;
import org.influxdb.dto.Point;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

public class ActiveMQToInfluxDbRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final String MESSAGE_HEADER = "InfluxTimestamp";

    @BindToRegistry
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory registerActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
        System.out.println("ActiveMQ Listener: STARTING...");
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://172.17.0.8:61616");
        connectionFactory.setUserName("admin");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("admin");
        connectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(false);
        connectionFactory.setClientID("Influx Message Queue");
        connectionFactory.setConnectResponseTimeout(300);
        System.out.println("ActiveMQ Listener: STARTED");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    String sourceString = "activemq:queue:cryring_db_inbound?brokerURL=tcp://172.17.0.8:61616";
    String targetString = "influxdb://influxDb?databaseName=my_database=true&retentionPolicy=default";

    from(sourceString) //
      .process(messagePayload -> {
           String manipulation stuff
      })//
     .to(targetString) //
     .onException(Exception.class) //
     .useOriginalMessage() //
     .handled(true) //
     .log("error") //
     .to("stream:out");
    }
```

The execution of the java code fails due with the exception:

```
Route(route1)[From[activemq:queue:my_database?brokerU... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: activemq://queue:my_database?brokerURL=tcp%3A%2F%2F172.17.0.8%3A61616 due to: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

I found already this post with a similar issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13145
but I cannot figure out what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solv it myself:

As stated in post https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13145, and what I didn't understand in the first place, the dependency `-d mvn:org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel:5.15.11` causes a problem. The ActiveMQ issue goes away if I run camel-K as follows:

```
kamel run kamel-integrations/ActiveMQToInfluxDbRoute.java -d mvn:org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9 -d mvn:org.influxdb:influxdb-java:2.17 -d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-activemq:3.0.1 -d mvn:org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.25.0
```

Comment: Youshould not require to add a dependency on camel core as it is added by default